# How to render component (home page) outside my Layout component?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-router-dom

I have a Layout component which consists of a header and left side navigation.
I'm using react router dom to render my routes inside the Layout. This works great. But I need to render a LandingPage component outside my Layout and I don't know how to do it properly.

See code in my App.js file.

```
const App = () => {
  let routes = (
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={ LandingPage } />
      <Route path="/path1" component={ PathOne } />
      <Route path="/path2" component={ PathTwo } />
    </Switch>
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <main>
        <Layout>
          { routes }
        </Layout>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const App = () => {
  let routes = (
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={ LandingPage } />
      <SomeRoute path="/path1" component={ PathOne } />
      <SomeRoute path="/path2" component={ PathTwo } />
    </Switch>
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <main>
          { routes }
      </main>
    </div>
  );
};

const someRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
    return (
    <Route {...rest} render={props => <Layout><Component {...props} /></Layout>} />}
    )
}
```

You can do like this. Hope this works.

This is example how to do it in docs. https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow